# Fixing Axis values in PPT Charts

Tags: vba, powerpoint, axis

I have ppt file scatter chart in each slide with more than 300 slides. I want to fix the X and Y axis values as auto for all the charts. How can it be done using VBA.

Comment: Please post the code which you have made so far. We can help you out once you have done your own research on the said topic. StackOverFlow is not a code-provider service.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you in the right direction:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
```

See: [Axis.MaximumScaleIsAuto property (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.axis.maximumscaleisauto)